# Is $\{0, 3\}$ a subset of $\{\{0\},\{3\},2\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Either I'm over thinking, either I just can't wrap my head around this.

For example, does $\{1\}$ equal $\{\{1\}\}$?

Comment: No, they are not equal. One set contains an element, the other contains a set.

Comment: Since $\{\{1\}\}\ne\emptyset$, by the axiom of regularity there must be an element $x\in\{\{1\}\}$ such that $\{\{1\}\}\cap x=\emptyset$. But the only element of $\{\{1\}\}$ is $\{1\}$. Hence, $\{1\}\cap \{\{1\}\}=\emptyset$. In particular, $\{1\}\ne\{\{1\}\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I did read the axiom of regularity but can't say I still quite understand it. For example... ∅ ∈ ∅ is this a true statement? What about ∅ ∈ { ∅ }?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\{0,3\}$ is not a subset of $\{\{0\},\{3\},2\}$, although $\{\{0\},\{3\}\}$ is. Do you see the difference?
In fact, $\{\{1\}\}$ is different than $\{1\}$. While they both contain a single element, the former contains the set $\{1\}$ while the latter contains the number $1$.

Comment: I will. Tried already, said I have to wait 9 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. {1} does not equal {{1}}. It's a bit easier to remove one set and just compare 1 to {1}. The first is the number 1, and the second is the set containing the number 1. These are not the same thing.